# Iam trying to make an qrcode by compressing the text to convert to qr code in following way

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It works on every android smartphone except tablet and it shows null object reference

```
String qrBase64 ="Hello World...!";
    qrgEncoder = new QRGEncoder(qrBase64, null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT, dimen);
    
            try {
                bitmap = qrgEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                String imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String image2 = "data:image/png;base64," + imageBase64;
                data = data.replace("{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}", image2);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                Log.e("Tag", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: show us the error and what is the android version of the tablet?

Comment: android 9 and i run this on one of my client devices

Comment: did you try to run on any other android device with version 9? is it working?

Comment: It shows like java.lang.nullpointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$compressFormat, int,java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: @UsamaAltaf yes it is working fine

Comment: your bitmap lines are returning null check in the log what is the problem

Comment: try this  : https://github.com/chtgupta/QRUtils-Android

Comment: try this:
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>

add this on manifest file